# Time different in Javascript Date Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have created an application in angularjs in which i have added a javascript date for the date `21/10/2014 07:30AM`, To make it into date object i did like as shown below

```
 new Date(2014, 10, 21, 07, 30);
```

but interestingly when i print it out i got like

```
2014-11-21T13:30:00.000Z
```

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4j4dxy5/)**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myValues = {};
    $scope.myValues.start = new Date(2014, 10, 21, 07, 30);
});
```

Can anyone please tell me why the time is different, also how can i correct that since i am saving this in database through php, Also many areas i need to get only the time

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy bose this is regard with time not month, also i know that month in javascript starts from 0-11

Comment: the difference would mostly be equal to your timezone offset. you should add/remove timezone effect, or try to print it using `$scope.myValues.start.toISOString()`

Comment: @harish how we can add that......

Comment: It looks like a timezone issue to me. Are you in the Central American timezone by any chance?

Comment: @AlexMan use toISOString method to print it

Comment: this is regarding timezone.

Comment: You might want to look at this question which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841413/angularjs-global-date-timezone-offset

Comment: i tried `$scope.myValues.start = new Date(2014, 10, 21, 07, 30);
    $scope.mydate = $scope.myValues.start.toISOString();  but still i got `2014-11-21T13:30:00.000Z`

Comment: try this one `$scope.myValues.start.toLocaleString();`

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha now i am getting `11/21/2014, 7:30:00 AM` but cant save this as datetime object in database table, also how can i change this string back to date object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can do some custom formatting

separate year,month day hour .. and rearrange them to create a sql `datetime` compatible string

here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwwfer0b/1/)

Comment: here also why i am not able to get it as `2014-11-21 07:30:00` instead of `2014-11-21 01:30:00`

Comment: updated the fiddle please check

Comment: how abt this http://jsfiddle.net/ewd16whe/

Comment: yes its fine but your question said that the date object like `new Date(2014, 10, 21, 07, 30)`

Comment: yes there also i am using `$scope.myDate =  new Date('2014-11-21 07:30:00'); `