# Angular show wrong time with unknown timezone

Tags: angularjs

flight.departure_at is a UTC format `2016-05-04T19:00:00.000Z`

When I display this expression in the page,

It's format is totally out of expectation.

Why does the 12:00 come out? How come?

I also want to know how could I keep all the time format in UTC globally without adding options everywhere. It will make the whole App vulnerable

## code

```
Departure_time: {{flight.departure_at}} ||| {{flight.departure_at | date: 'HH:mm'}}
```

## output

```
Departure_time: 2016-05-04T19:00:00.000Z ||| 12:00
```

Comment: This might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841413/angularjs-global-date-timezone-offset

Comment: @Danieboy you saved me !! thanks~

Answer (score 0):

This standard is called ISO-8601 and the format is: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

`'T'` is just a separator between date and time in ISO-8601 format.

`'Z'` is zero time zone ( your getting 12:00 , because it convert to your timezone)

we can use parse like this ,

```
var date = new Date('2016-05-04T19:00:00.000Z');
console.log(date.getUTCHours()); // Hours - 19
console.log(date.getUTCMinutes()); //0
console.log(date.getUTCSeconds());// 0


console.log(Date.parse(date));
console.log(new Date(Date.parse(date)));
```

OR

`Date.parse(DATE)` for getting time in standard time format

[UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a different thread about personalizing timezones to the user - I've found this to be very helpful when coming to dealing with timezones in Angular. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161107/3585278)

```
module.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
var DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = 'GMT';

$provide.decorator('dateFilter', ['$delegate', '$injector', function($delegate, $injector) {
    var oldDelegate = $delegate;

    var standardDateFilterInterceptor = function(date, format, timezone) {
        if(angular.isUndefined(timezone)) {
            timezone = DEFAULT_TIMEZONE;
        }
    return oldDelegate.apply(this, [date, format, timezone]);
    };

    return standardDateFilterInterceptor;
    }]);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) for all date time related stuff for the frontend and [moment](http://momentjs.com/) for the controller part.

You should store all time as UTC in backend and then on frontend you can set user's timezone globally as

```
app.constant('angularMomentConfig', {
  'timezone' : <user's timezone> 
});
```

Render UTC time now on frontend without worrying about timezone(make sure all variables are either `moment` or `Date` object):

```
<td ng-bind="flight.departure_at| amDateFormat:'HH:mm'"></td>
```